# What does “E!” mean in the phrases, a show “makes the debut Sunday E! sets in motion,” and “premiers on E! April 21”?

Tags: meaning

I came across a new interjection (seemingly) “E!” in the following sentence of the [Washington Post (April 18) article](http://www.washingtonpost.com/entertainment/tv/ryan-lochte-keha-and-the-rules-for-celebrity-reality-shows/2013/04/18/ddb857a8-a706-11e2-a8e2-5b98cb59187f_story.html?hpid=z4) titled, “Ryan Lochte, Ke$ha and the rules for celebrity reality shows”.

> Ryan Lochte’s bold personal style: The Olympic swimmer’s reality series “What Would Ryan Lochte Do?” **premires on E!** April 21.
>
> This week marks the debut of two such shows. **Sunday, E!** sets in motion “What Would Ryan Lochte Do?,” a look at the Olympic swimmer who
>   made headlines at last year’s London games — not so much for his
>   victories and friendly rivalry with teammate Michael Phelps as for a
>   flurry of awkward interviews and self-deluded sound bites
>   (trademarking the **frat-thusiastic** phrase “**Jeah**!”) that gave him a
>   party-boy reputation.

What does “E!” mean? Is it an interjection or a capital letter for something associated with TV entertainment programs?

Additionally, is “Jeah” similar with “gee / jee”? Is the word, “ frat-thusiastic” which I presume to be a compound of “fraternity + enthusiastic” (Pls. correct me if I’m wrong) a current English word, or just a coinage by the author?

Comment: The answer was the first result by Googling the E!:http://www.eonline.com/

Comment: I assume "Jeah" is "yeah", yelled, as a loud and abrupt interjection, so that the 'y' turns into a 'dj' sound; American men performing hypermasculine bonding behavior (often associated with college fraternities) will make such a sound when their favored sports team scores a goal -- hence "frat-thusiastic", which is definitely not a term in wide use.

Comment: To those who voted for closing this question: Please have in mind that besides four of you 'close voters,'some of them are habitual, there are 258 users right now who were perhaps interested in reading this question and don’t feel the need to close it. Isn’t it unfair if only 4 -5 (2%) votes should control the rest of 258’s (98%) options?

Comment: Correction: 249 users, not 258.

Comment: What made you think "E!" has *anything* to do with the English Language & Usage? Care to answer? Does "I am speaking to Yoichi Oishi" prompt you to post a question like "What does Yoichi Oishi mean?"

Comment: If "E!" isn't an English onomastic, is it Chinese, Russian, Greek, Arabic, or Martian language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to "E!" being the stylized logo for "Entertainment Television" and it's various intellectual properties, the company has a brand of being "Hollywood hip" and so takes liberties with the English language that are anything but standard.

Stylization in branding and art often includes punctuation and nonstandard capitalization, and is indeed confusing to those not familiar- which some would argue is not entirely accidental. An example beyond those already mentioned include the band "fun." and the internet/company "del.icio.us". This has the somewhat amusing side-effect of making the convention of putting punctuation inside quotes problematic, but that's tangential.

On your other questions, "Jeah" is pretty much just an altered pronunciation of "yeah" meant to convey an attitude related to the word "duh"; it's sarcastic, like a stereotypical immature "frat boy".

The word "frat-tastic" is also slightly different in meaning than you expected, as it is using [-tastic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-tastic) as an adjective in a combining form. The statement means to convey that the man is especially like a stereotypical fraternity member. The similarity to "enthusiastic" is more or less accidental, as "-tastic" comes from "fantastic". The "-tastic" suffix is in general use, and the author is relying on familiarity with the convention rather than with the "frat-tastic" example itself being a word in common use.

Comment: Urban Dictionary defines ‘jeah’ as ‘a cool way to say "yeah" or "yes", but is being hijacked by Olympian Ryan Lochte to mean anything." But it doesn’t show its pronunciation. How do you pronounce ‘jeah’?  ji:ə, yi:ə, or otherwise?

Comment: Gee! I missed that Russell Borogove already told me that the 'y' turns into a 'dj' sound in his comment. So please neglect the above question.

Answer (score 8):

E! is an entertainment company. The exclamation point is part of their name, so it does not affect the sentence structure or pronunciation.

http://www.eonline.com/

Comment: There's plenty of names with exclamations in them, such as Yahoo!, Airplane!, just to confound grammar checkers it seems.

Comment: @Cong: I'm getting lots of squiggly lines with _I Googled my iPhone to find E!, Yahoo!, and WebMD._

Comment: When you see a question that's not related to the English Language & Usage, you vote to close it as Off Topic.

Comment: They might as well get an answer to their question before closing it off.

Comment: Kris. Thank you for chasing after every my question meticulously. I know you are the 'close and down vote' enthusiast. But be aware that there are 276 viewers who wanted to read this question bona fide besides you. I know you don’t like all of my questions, or hate me as a non-native English speaker, if so, why don’t you stop wasting your precious time in sticking around my questions just for the purpose of booing and closing and down-voting.

Comment: Cont. Please don't behave like a stalker. It's unconstructive, and terribly bad for mental health for both of us, and peer  users.